# System.Management.Automation.Powershell.Invoke() claims HadErrors when there were none

Tags: c#, git, powershell, command-line

I'm having an issue with the following code where it works fine on computers who have Powershell version 1-4 but when ran on a computer with Powershell V5, the test, "posh.HadErrors" is returning true. I tried this on a clean vagrant install so it's not a profile or env var issue. Any git command I try running, powershell claims to have errors when running on a computer with v5 installed. I'm not even sure how to debug this issue.

```
using (var posh = PowerShell.Create())
{
    string resultString = "";
    posh.AddScript("git checkout master");
    var results = posh.Invoke();
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        if (result == null) { continue; }

        if (posh.HadErrors)
        {
            // This is getting hit when it shouldn't when running Powershell V5
            _console.LogError(result.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            resultString += result + "\r\n";
            _console.LogDebug(result.ToString());
        }
    }

    foreach (var error in posh.Streams.Error)
    {
        _console.LogError(error.ToString());
    }

    return Tuple.Create(!posh.HadErrors, resultString);
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? Maybe there is a issue with git on that machine?

Comment: Maybe `git` returns a non-zero exit code? Is `git` in PATH? Is current directory a git repo? If you examine `posh` in Quick watch do you see anything suspicious?

Comment: @cezarypiatek There is no error message, result contains whatever you'd normally expect (eg "Switched to branch master"). $LASTEXITCODE is 0.

Comment: @wOxxOm Git is in the path, like I said it correctly does the command it just incorrectly reports that it has an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git outputs to stderr even when there's no error.

E.g. if it looks like this:

```
> git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

That first line is error output.

If it looks like this:

```
> git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

That first line is *still* error output.

You can verify it by running the command like this:

```
git checkout master 1>output.log 2>error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Id HadErroes equal true, check `PowerShellInstance.InvocationStateInfo.Reason` to see the exception